# Cooling my graphics card quietly

Tags: graphics-card, cooling, nvidia-geforce, silent-cooling

The loudest component in my computer is the graphics card. I have an ASUS GTX 690. I would like to find a way to make it quieter. I have decided to look into replacing the fan. Would doing that void the warranty on the graphics card? I constructed the computer from parts purchased online.

I've looked around and the only cooling solution I could find was the [Accelero Twin Turbo 690](http://www.arctic.ac/en/p/cooling/vga/598/accelero-twin-turbo-690.html?c=2182), is there anything else I could consider?

I have a [Silverstone SST-TJ08E](http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=303) case and I think there's room in there for a cooler of some sort.

Here is a picture of what it looks like inside the case
[image: inside the case]
*There's over an inch of space above the graphics card*
*There are no hard drives in the hard drive cage space to the left of the CPU cooler*

I have no experience with liquid cooling, to be honest I'm frightened of trying it. But if I did I think there would be room for a reservoir in the lower 5.25 drive bay.

Has anyone with a similar setup had a go at changing the fan on a GTX 690?

Comment: You bought a $1k, dual GPU monster and expect it to be quiet? Who is the OEM? EVGA, ASUS ect. They will be the one who provide the warranty, you should check if a 3rd party cooler will void the warranty with them. Also, these cards have a special vapor chamber cooler on them, so at best you would probably only replace the fans unless you decide to use a custom loop.

Comment: @Kyle it's actually pretty quiet when idle and I haven't noticed any noise while playing games because I have headphones on while I'm doing that. Most of the time the traffic outside my window drowns out any noise that the card makes, but intermittently during the day and late in the evenings I can hear it quite clearly. I'm about to move it to a quieter location, so the noise will be more noticeable. Have you changed the fan on a card like this before? Is there any danger of ruining the vapor chamber, I like to think that I could put it back the way it was should I choose to.

Comment: I remember reading that there was something special about the vapor chamber on the 690, but I could be wrong. I have never added a non stock vapor chamber but I have taken them off to reapply TIM and cleaning. I do that at least once a year on my PC's.

Comment: Just a comment: Not all water coolers are quieter than normal cooling. Liquid cooling is mostly useful moving the heat to another location. Then it still has to get rid of it.

Comment: @Kyle after some time has passed, i conclude that i was wrong, it's not the graphics card making the noise, it's the cpu cooler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard work to make a top of the line high performance computer quite. A more simple solution is actually try to dampen the sound as much as possible.

If there is not yet sound-absorbing material in your case door. Invest in it before doing anything else. It will not quite the gtx by much, but it's a cheap way to get the case just slightly less noisy.

Another thing you can consider is moving the whole machine to another room or closet, then using a 5meter hdmi and 5meter usb to your desktop. (5meter is usb and hdmi limit).
If you consider all the work of watercooling that is actually cheap. If you have the space to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant ideas! I haven't put any kind of sound absorbing materials into the case, I'll look into that. Unfortunately it will be hard to put the machine into a cupboard, but I will give that some thought, I need to think about how hot it would be in an enclosed space and how air would get in there. putting it in a different room would certainly solve the problem, but I think I'd get tangled up in the logistics of doing that

Comment: Try avoiding a too enclosed space. You don't want to cause a fire. Also if your room is very bare, noise is more easily transmitted through the room. Try putting in some soft furniture, carpets, and heavy drapes. A ghettohack: I actually dampend a server of mine quite alot by simple putting a chair infront of it, and hanging a  heavy winter jacket on the chair. Like this.  [me] [chairwithjacket] [server]. <- dampend the high frequency sound by alot.